# Gareth/php-ews , how to get sent mail items

Tags: php, email, exchangewebservices

```
use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword('server', 'username', 'password');
$mail = $api->getMailItems();

foreach ($mail as $mailItem) {
    $mailItem = $api->getItem($mail->getItemId());
    $subject = $mailItem->getSubject();
    $body = (string) $mailItem->getBody();
}
```

The above code return all exchange inbox emails.

But I need only sent items. Is there a way to filter out the sent emails specifically. Can some one let me know how can I get only the emails that are sent out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.